# Should I trust library initializer function was called in favor of performance?

Tags: c

I am creating a library in C (not C++), and had a question regarding what is common practice.

This library requires a `%libname%_Init()` function to be called so the other functions can perform their appropriate duties (if not, undefined/unexpected behavior are bound to happen, possibly leading to crashes).

I *could* easily check on the top of every function if it was called with a simple `if (%random_var%)`, so I wanted to know if there is a convention on this.

Ps¹: A real example would be `SDL.h` requiring `SDL_Init( /*modules to be initialized */ )`

Ps²: I do apologize if `stackoverflow` is not the place for this kind of question

Comment: I think it depends on whether you afford the overhead of checking in every function call, but depending on how much performance you need, I don't think it will be such a huge overhead. However, you could use a struct with all the data needed for your functions to perform and force the caller to initialize it, and pass it to each function, I have seen this technique a lot for instance see the `cairo` drawing library.

Comment: You could use an `assert()` that would fail if the library isn't initialized. That way release performance isn't compromised and debug builds clearly catch the error. Now, whether or not you *should* do this one way or another might be question better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind exploiting gcc's (and others' possibly) extensions, you might have a look at `__attribute__ ((constructor))` (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) which guarantees that a function is called immediately prior to `main()`. That way you *know* your init function has been called.

However, in the general case, if your library needs initializing, it's probably doing it wrong. You probably want to avoid using globals at all in libraries, and that means you don't want to be using this kind of init function.

As an example of a great library which fell into this trap, look at `libxml2`. It has an init function you need to call that allocates memory. In order for anyone to see a clean output from (e.g.) `valgrind` they need to free up the memory this allocates, so they have to call a deinit function; of course only some applications do this. So far so good. But what then happens if another library (libfoo) also uses `libxml2`? They both call the init function (great). But who if anyone calls the deinit function? If libfoo doesn't call it, then anything using libfoo will leak memory. If libfoo does call it, then anything using libfoo can't use libxml2 after its done with libfoo. A nasty mess (acknowledged by the author).

A better strategy is each user to get a context for the library (with a single call, returning a pointer), which allocates a `struct` containing what you would otherwise have used as global variables. This pointer is passed to every call. That way you *know* the init function must have been called, as that's the only way to obtain such a pointer. Also, your library is pretty much automatically thread-safe provided each context is only used by one thread (obviously you need to avoid using any functions which themselves rely on global variables). An example:

```
 BarContext context = bar_newcontext();
 ...
 bar_dosomething (context, ...);
 ...
 bar_freecontext (context);
```

Comment: All of your answer is very useful. Thanks for the help.
I will be implementing this struct context right now.